# CASE returns more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
select a.Tag,a.Type, a.[Starting Date], a.[Time From 1], a.[Time To 1], 
       DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date) as [TagderWoche], CBCal.Date, CBCal.[Customer No_],
       Description, [POS Holiday] 
       from [ReplicationLayer].[BackPro].[CustomerBPCal] as CBCal 
CROSS APPLY
(
    select Type,[Starting Date],[Time From 1],[Time To 1] ,
    (case 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=1 then (select [Time From 1] from MyTable 
                                              where [Valid at Monday]=1 
                                              and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_] ) 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=3 then (select [Time From 1] from MyTable 
                                              where [Valid at Wednesday]=1 
                                              and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_]) 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=4 then (select [Time From 1] from MyTable 
                                              where [Valid at Thursday]=1 
                                              and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_])
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=5 then (select [Time From 1] from MyTable 
                                              where [Valid at Friday]=1 
                                              and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_]) 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=6 then (select [Time From 1] from MyTable 
                                              where [Valid at Saturday]=1 
                                              and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_]) 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=7 then (select [Time From 1] from MyTable 
                                              where [Valid at Sunday]=1 
                                              and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_])
    end) as Tag
    from  [CustomerShopAndArrivalTime]
) as a
where CBCal.[Customer No_]=1 and CBCal.[POS Holiday]=0 and Date='2015-04-15'
```

If I run this query I am getting this error:
    Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, = or when the subquery is used as an expression.

what should I do to solve this problem

Comment: Consider why your sub-selects may return more than 1 row. When that's the case, what do you want do to?

Comment: It is the case problem, and I want to only run one query in CASE. I think more than one SELECT ar run in the CASE

Comment: Case has another syntax in which you use the value once and then multiple case values: `CASE Value WHEN 1 THEN ... WHEN 2 THEN ...`

Comment: I would like to have´if DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=1´ then this query´select [Time From 1] from MyTable where [Valid at Monday]=1 and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_]´ and so on...

Comment: It's not caused by the `CASE`. You'd have exactly the same issue if you replaced your entire `CASE` expression with, say, `(select [Time From 1] from MyTable where [Valid at Monday]=1 and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_] )`. That is, you're at a point in your query where you're meant to provide an *expression* that produces *a* value. And you've written something that returns *multiple* values. The system doesn't know what to do.

Comment: Only one `CASE` block is executed, the problem is with the subselects, that return more than one row where only one is expected.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, do you have any idea, how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function max, min or top like this

```
    select a.Tag,
           a.Type,
           a.[Starting Date],
           a.[Time From 1],
           a.[Time To 1], 
           DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date) as [TagderWoche], 
           CBCal.Date, 
           CBCal.[Customer No_],
           Description,[POS Holiday] 
from [ReplicationLayer].[BackPro].[CustomerBPCal] as CBCal 
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    select Type,[Starting Date],[Time From 1],[Time To 1] ,
    (case 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=1 then 
                      (select top 1 [Time From 1] from MyTable where [Valid at Monday]=1 and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_] ) 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=3 then  
                      (select top 1 [Time From 1] from MyTable where [Valid at Wednesday]=1 and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_]) 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=4 then  
                      (select top 1 [Time From 1] from MyTable where [Valid at Thursday]=1 and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_])
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=5 then 
                      (select top 1 [Time From 1] from MyTable where [Valid at Friday]=1 and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_]) 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=6 then  
                      (select top 1 [Time From 1] from MyTable where [Valid at Saturday]=1 and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_]) 
         WHEN DATEPART(dw,CBCal.Date)=7 then 
                      (select top 1 [Time From 1] from MyTable where [Valid at Sunday]=1 and [Customer No_]=CBCal.[Customer No_])
      end) as Tag
        from  [CustomerShopAndArrivalTime]
    ) as a
    where CBCal.[Customer No_]=1 and CBCal.[POS Holiday]=0 and Date='2015-04-15'
```

Comment: I would like to have all data not only the one

Comment: @kaja  it is only to possible  all record to return coma separated.

Comment: @Kaja, do you want additional rows in the final result when the `CASE` scalar expression returns more than one row?  Otherwise, you'll need to return a delimited list of values like Mukesh suggested.